Why am I getting multiple cracks on my drywall ceiling?
Found drywall cracks on my ceiling (2nd floor above basement, attic above). They all run parallel, seemingly on seams. It has been very humid recently but I want to make sure that this is just a cosmetic concern. Saw that some websites say that multiple cracks could be a structural concern. Found a crack in another room that looks very similar but gong in the perpendicular direction. Is it just humidity/bad installation or could it be something more serious?




Are the cracks 4 or 8 feet apart, and are they all parallel and/or perpendicular?

@Huesmann pretty evenly spaced and parallel.

Sounds to me like it's just crappily taped drywall joints.

@Huesmann thanks. Eyeballing it looks like 4ft. Was nervous because multiple showed up at similar times.

It's impossible to tell from just a picture. Most likely, it's just the result of a bad taping job -- the picture shows some sloppy work when applying joint compound to the seams.
However, it could also be a sign of something more serious, for example, a sinking foundation.
To determine the true cause, you would need to look for more clues. Usual signs of a sinking foundation include cracks in the drywall/plaster above openings (windows and doors), doors frames moving (doors don't close easily as they used to), and of course, cracks in the actual foundation.

Thanks. Not seeing those things. The house is over 100 years old so obviously some quirks. Concerned because multiple showed up at similar times.
